# Error de conversión de String a Double al concatener con + en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una rutina para grabar en una Base de datos Access:

```
Private Sub btnGba_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGba.Click
    Dim rsl As Boolean
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim Nro As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    If bNvo = True Then         ' Nuevo Registro
        Txt = "INSERT INTO AccesoMenu (NmgMnu) VALUES (" + NomGpo.Text + ")"
    Else                        ' Modifica existente
        Txt = "UPDATE AccesoMenu SET NmgMnu=" + NomGpo.Text
    End If
    rsl = ActualizaBD(Txt)
    LlenaArray()

    For i = 0 To 9
        If bNvo = True Then
            Txt = "INSERT INTO AccMenuLin (NroMnu,LinMnu,ConMnu,AgrMnu,EliMnu,GloMnu) VALUES (" + Nro _
                + "," + i + "," + C1(i) + "," + A1(i) + "," + E1(i) + "," + G1(i) + ")"
        Else
            *Txt = "UPDATE AccMenuLin SET NroMnu=" + Nro + "(,LinMnu=)" + i + ",ConMnu=" + C1(i) + ",AgrMnu=" + A1(i) + ",EliMnu=" + E1(i) + ",GloMnu=" + G1(i)*
        End If
        rsl = ActualizaBD(Txt)
    Next
    If NrRegSQL > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Registro agregado o actualizado con exito!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Error al actualizar regitro!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Como se puede ver se trata de actualizar dos tablas, tipo Maestro/detalle. en la linea marcada como itálicas (*) recibo el error:

```
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2147467262
HelpLink: Nothing
InnerException: {"La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto."}
Message: "La conversión de la cadena ""UPDATE AccMenuLin SET NroMnu="" en el tipo 'Double' no es válida."
Source: "Microsoft.VisualBasic"
StackTrace: "   en Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)" & vbCrLf & "   en Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value)"
TargetSite: {Double ToDouble(System.String, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)}
```

Y a la verdad no entiendo el error, ya que no estoy tratando de convertir nada a double. Ni entiendo por qué VS interpreta la cadena como una conversión.

Alguien sabrá algo de esto?

Answer (score 2):

El problema se encuentra en los strings para armar la instrucción SQL.

Siempre se le debe colocar a todas las variables numéricas el adicional `ToString`; es decir, basándome en la línea con error:

```
Txt = "UPDATE AccMenuLin SET NroMnu=" + Nro.ToString + "(,LinMnu=)" + i.ToString + ",ConMnu=" + 
C1(i).ToString + ",AgrMnu=" + A1(i).ToString + ",EliMnu=" + E1(i).ToString + ",GloMnu=" + G1(i).ToString
```

Contesto mi pregunta por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar `String.Format()`[►](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim sUpdate$ = "UPDATE AccMenuLin SET NroMnu = {0}, LinMnu = {1}, ConMnu = {2}, AgrMnu = {3}, EliMnu = {4}, GloMnu = {5}"
Txt = String.Format(sUpdate, Nro, i, C1(i), A1(i), E1(i), G1(i))
```